# unix printing files (simple txt files )with pages numbers

Tags: linux, printing, lp

I am using the command `lp -d (printer_name) *` to print all files in the current directory.

How can I print the page number also:

> 'Page-1' or '1'

on each page per file printed?

Comment: To print simple text files with page numbers look at `enscript`.

Comment: That example is confusing.  Should *"or"* be printed a the bottom of each page?

Comment: What kind of files? Text files? Use `pr`. Pdf or postscript files? That's more difficult. What do you use for printing? CUPS?

Comment: Other tools which can do the things you describe are `a2ps` (mostly for text files) and the latex package `pdfpages` (on which various tools like `pdfbook` are based, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603301/how-to-add-page-numbers-to-postscript-pdf#1608046) for pdf files.You see it depends on the context, you should be more precise about this in your question.

Comment: `lpr` has a `-p` option: Specifies that the print file should be formatted with a shaded header with the date, time, job name, and page number.